# titlepage environment - no control sequence is recognized

Tags: titles

I am using 2 templates from [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation) for creating a title page for a document. One template is for testing and the other one for the titlepage itself. They are shown below. The problem I have is that I am getting undefined control sequence within the titlepage environment even for the most basic latex commands. I can't figure out what to do. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}
\end{document}
```

title.tex contains this:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\Huge{Title goes here}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{titlepage}
```

No matter what I put inside titlepage, even just \text{something}, it still gives undefined control sequence. Please help!

Comment: This is really weird, but I just compiled once again and it's working now. I really don't know what is happening, but good thing it's working now!!!